# Разные шрифты на странице, как сделать?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Хочу сделать разные шрифты для заголовка и для описания, как я могу это сделать? Как подключить второй шрифт на страницу? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В стиле для указанных элементов указать другой шрифт: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/font-family и https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/font-size А на скриншоте разве разные шрифты? По моему, только разный размер, шрифт один

Comment: Шрифт один, вот я и спрашиваю как сделать два разных, в заголовке один, а в описании другой

Comment: `Как подключить второй шрифт на страницу? ` второй шрифт это другой шрифт, типа Arial и Times New Roman. Добавьте в те теги `class` и в css пропишите для указанных `class` размер

Comment: А если я хочу добавить шрифт не стандартный? Которого нет в браузере или на компьютере? как поступить тогда?

Comment: Указать на него ссылку, чтобы браузер мог его скачать: http://htmlbook.ru/blog/svoi-shrift-na-stranitse и https://stackoverflow.com/a/107951/5909792

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: Пожалуйста ) оформите, пожалуйста, сами ответ с решением проблемы :)

Comment: Вроде бы все сделал

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы изменить шрифт у какого-либо из элементов нужно использовать css-свойство
font-family (developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/font-family).

Если нужно поставить нестандартный шрифт, надо указать браузеру на него ссылку, чтобы браузер мог его скачать (htmlbook.ru/blog/svoi-shrift-na-stranitse и stackoverflow.com/a/107951/5909792).

За помощь огромное спасибо - gil9red.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте CSS:

```
h1 {  
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

div {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: А как добавить "кастомный" шрифт?